# Does anyone else experience this "browser-freeze" problem?

Tags: discussion, support

Both MathJax & ChatJax freeze my chrome and IE7 browsers running on Windows Vista for at least 2 minutes while it loads. The entire bowser is unresponsive, I can't even click on the start;
sometimes the pointer doesn't even move.

Comment: In short: yes, but not on the load; rather in the middle of typing an answer. It is not unusual that even the browser gets tired of it and suggests to turn off the script on the page after a couple of minutes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is a somewhat general problem, as the site can be quite demanding on resources.

See these meta.math.SE questions

1. [Internet explorer experiences “freeze” when first accessing math stackexchange](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5056/internet-explorer-experiences-freeze-when-first-accessing-math-stackexchange)
2. [Minor nag with MathJax freezing computer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6391/minor-nag-with-mathjax-freezing-computer)

A propsed solution (yet for firefox), is turn of harware accelaration of the browser. Something analogous might/should exist and work for other browers, too.

Comment: It would help if unnecessary TeXing was avoided especially in titles.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg I completely agree (as expressed elsewhere in more detail), especially for titles. But I am afraid it will not happen.